# Factors that affect energy of a sound wave?

Tags: energy, waves, acoustics, frequency

Putting a lot of energy into a transverse pulse will not effect the wavelength, the frequency or the speed of the pulse. The energy imparted to a pulse will only affect the amplitude of that pulse.why is it like that?

Comment: Are you asking about a pulse on a string?

Comment: no i am asking about a sound wave . maybe you can answer for longitudinal waves in general

Comment: So where has the transverse pulse come from if you are asking about sound waves in air which are longitudinal waves?

Comment: from vibrations

Comment: It's like that for every type of wave, until it enters a nonlinear regime. what does that suggest to you?